# oracle sql about table.substr

Tags: sql, oracle, substr

something wrong with my sql

environment：oracle 12C

--table.title is available, and sql below is works

```
select substr(title,0,length(title)-8)  from table
```

--but this sql didn't work how to fix it?

```
SELECT tableA.something
FROM tableA 
LEFT JOIN table
on tableA.name = table.substr(0,LENGTH(title)-8)
```

--output

> "table"."SUBSTR":invalid identifier

thx.

Comment: You are applying your table reference to the substr function, thus making Oracle think that you're trying to reference a column in that table. As Jarlh has shown, you need to add the table reference to its column(s) instead. Also, why are you passing 0 as the first parameter of substr? If you're just wanting the last 8 characters of the column, `substr(table.title, -8)` would do instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust your syntax to:

```
SELECT tableA.something
FROM tableA 
LEFT JOIN table
on tableA.name = substr(table.title, LENGTH(table.title)-8)
```

`table.title` is an argument to the `LENGTH()` function. Also needs to be argument to `SUBSTR()`.

Comment: You can improve the sql using the left join special oracle syntax using plus "+" symbol. So, `SELECT tableA.something FROM tableA WHERE tableA.name(+) = substr(table.title, LENGTH(table.title)-8)`. Both methods are valid, but in my opinion is clearer and simpler... maybe only is an habit of mine. :)

Comment: @OscarAkaElvis, I stick to the ANSI SQL version of the syntax (mainly because it's portable and understood by everybody.)

Comment: Nice, is only a suggestion... not for your answer... is more to the user asking. Maybe it can help him.

Comment: @OscarAkaElvis in general, ANSI join syntax is the way forward. There are cases where it doesn't work and you have to use the old-style syntax, but in other cases it's much more flexible than the old-style syntax (e.g. full outer join). You should consider making the switch (and I speak as someone who resisted switching to the ANSI syntax for several years!)